# How do I use the /playsound command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am completely unfamiliar with this command, but I want to know how to use it.

Normally all I have to do is type `/[example]` and then press tab, and a bunch of options will show up. For an example, when I do `/particle` [tab] then a lot of particle effects will pop up. But it does nothing when I try the `/playsound` command. Is there something I need to add to a folder or something?

Also, I don't completely understand the rest of the command either. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `/playsound` command as follows:

```
  /playsound soundname (@p for closest player @a for all or @r for random player) x y z volume pitch minvolume
```

The volume, pitch and player are optional

A list of sounds can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json) in the sound event column.

Comment: Warning: The link may give you eye cancer. I suggest you link to the wiki instead, as the list you linked is incomplete as well. Although the wiki link needs some explanation on how to use it with playsound. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sounds.json

Comment: @MrLemon This is true. I am changing the link before more people get hurt.